# Move site from MySQL to MS SQL

Tags: database

I've been trying to move an existing Drupal 7 site from a MySQL database to an MS SQL database. The tables and their contents has been successfully moved. I've seen some errors in datatypes and default values, but these has been manually altered.

The site is now working, well, almost working as it should. At the bottom of each page, I'm getting an error message stating:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]The data types ntext and nvarchar are incompatible in the not equal to operator. in drupal_write_record()
```

I've been comparing some core tables from a fresh Drupal installation, and the datatypes ar the same.

Is this a database related error or a Drupal related error? Am I even posting this question at the right place? Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/dbtng_migrator looks interesting. Not an answer but may help later on. :)

Comment: That seems like a promising module, with a short issue queue. I'm doing a migration from MySQL to MS SQL at this very moment, stay tuned :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DBTNG Migrator](http://drupal.org/project/dbtng_migrator) module is in fact a great choice. I've used it very successfully.

Comment: Seems like the right way to go. Getting Internal Server error, but that's probably due to IIS. I've tested the module in another environment, and it works just as it should =)

Comment: And by the way, do not, under any circumstances, try to develop a site in a Windows environment. It truly sucks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the DBTNG Migrator, and it failed miserably for several reasons. I even had to patch it with my own fixes because a table field in the privatemsg module where named "public" that is a reserved key word in SQL Server.

I ended up using the "Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL" from Microsoft. It worked flawlessly and given the fact that they are the maker of SQL Server, why reinvent the wheel and waste your valuable time.

Do yourself a favour guys and use the tool provided from the DB Makers. Even MySQL Workbench can migration easily (few clicks) can migrate between MySQL and anything.

The good news is that all these tools are totally free.

Cheers